# Trying to use shredos to wipe a mac but running into difficulty

Tags: terminal, usb, boot

Having some trouble mounting shredos.img onto a usb flash drive. Running macOS Ventura 13.3.1. I'd like to mount shredos onto said usb and use it to boot from on a mac I purchased from my work - it's been part of an administered network, so obviously I'd like to unhook for personal use. Although it's been removed on their end from google admin and jamf, whenever I boot up it tries to run a whole bunch of network related stuff - it basically doesn't want to be independent and tries to rejoin the network. I have some experience with shredos - used it quite a bit at work for shredding end of life machines but have never burned it onto a usb.

When I ran:

```
dd if=shredos-2021.08.2_23_x86-64_0.34_20221231.img of=/dev/disk421
```

I got:

```
dd: shredos-2021.08.2_23_x86-64_0.34_20221231.img: No such file or directory
```

I then ran:

```
sudo -i
```

and then the first command, to no avail.

I then tried:

```
dd if=/Users/judahhooper/Downloads/shredos-2021.08.2_23_x86-64_0.34_20221231.img
 of=/dev/disk4s1
```

Which threw loads of numbers and question marks in the terminal and had me very worried. I then tried booting up the purchased mac in startup manager with the usb in but was only met with Macintosh HD (I expected something like EFI boot with an orange flash drive logo to appear). I'm pretty out of my depth now and would love if someone could provide a solution! The longer I mess around with shredos and nwipe the more likely it is I securely erase all my files eternally.

Comment: feel free to refer to the shredos documentation. I followed all the steps and no cigar:
https://github.com/PartialVolume/shredos.x86_64